# Javascript Splice dont work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to remove object from array,but it returning wrong.
i need to remove the meals that not have food.

[Array of meals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoyPt.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycCCq.png)

```
  $(meals).each(function (indexmeal,meal) {
        var hasfood = false;
        $(foods).each(function (index,food) {

            if(food.refeicao == meal.id)
            {
                hasfood = true;
            }

        });


        if(!hasfood)
        {
            console.log('remove meal id:'+ meal.id);
            meals.splice(meal.id,1);
        }
```

but the result it's to be only the first meal,that have food,but the result is not this,i tried and can't get the result =/
Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Yes,sorry,but i translated it,sorry for my bad english !

Comment: it's worked,i changed the $.each to for loop and worked ,cause i was removing the element inside the interation.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

You should use the index in the meals array for meal, not meal.id.

Comment: but meal.id is the same indexmeal,if you said about "meals.spice(meal.id,1)",thanks for helping !

Comment: Can you try meals = meals.splice(meal.id, 1); ?

Comment: i tried,dont worked,the splice is removing every loop,so the index change,to fix it i create a for loop and temp variable :),thanks for helping !